# Draw Textured Polygons in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm building a top-down scrolling game in SpriteKit and am trying to produce realistic terrain.  So far I've positioned and rotated overlapping sprites to create grassy fields, and now I'd like to add a river:

Positioning sprites doesn't allow enough control over the shape of the river - the edges look rather poor quality.  I'd like to draw a custom polygon with a texture - like a SKShape node with a texture.

Is there any way to perform custom drawing, or create a new SKNode subclass that will allow this?  Seems like there should be some "catch-all" method to access the graphics context during a node's render and do something with it, but I'm not finding it in the docs.

Comment: sprite + crop node with shape is what you could try

Comment: Use the Shape Node as a mask for a crop over a texture. You can't access SpriteKits context as far as I know but you can create an image context, draw whatever you want on it, and use the resulting image to create a SKTexture then a Sprite.

Comment: @AwDogsGo2Heaven Theoretically Shape node should work, however, in practice it appears to have some bugs right now.  Hopefully they will be fixed in 7.1, but with the current SDK it isn't functional.